# Python - open all txt files, remove empty lines and find a specific character

Tags: python

What I want to do:
a) open all files in directory (in this case: chapters from long stories)
b) remove all empty lines
c) find sentences started with "- " (in this case: dialogues)

I was able to create code that works well, but only for one file:

```
file = open('.\\stories\\test\\01.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-16 LE")
string_with_empty_lines = file.read() 

lines = string_with_empty_lines.split("\n") 
non_empty_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]

string_without_empty_lines = ""
for line in non_empty_lines:
  if line.startswith('- '):
    string_without_empty_lines += line + "\n"

print(string_without_empty_lines)
```

I started mixed up with this because I have a lot of files and I want to open them all and print the results from all files (and probably save all results to one file, but it's not necessary right now). The first part of the new code successfully open files (checked with commented print line), but when I add the part with editing, nothing happens at all (I don't even have errors in console).

```
import os
import glob

folder_path = os.path.join('G:' '.\\stories\\test')
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '**', '*.txt'), recursive=True):
  with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-16 LE") as f:
    string_with_empty_lines = f.read()
#    print(string_with_empty_lines)

lines = string_with_empty_lines.split("\n")
non_empty_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]

string_without_empty_lines = ""
for line in non_empty_lines:
  if line.startswith("- "):
    string_without_empty_lines += line + "\n"

print(string_without_empty_lines)
```

Comment: What do you *want* to happen, and what part of the code is supposed to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to happen with lines that start with '-'? Will they be saved in a new file or some other object?

"c) find sentences started with "- " (in this case: dialogues)"

Comment: Print in the console lines started with "- " from all 148 .txt files saved in directory, line under the line. The files are a mess because of a bad formatting with lot of blank lines, so I need to remove them, also. As I said, the first code is fine, but works only if I point to specific file. I'm trying to find a way to open all files and print the results. And just read by myself the dialogues from these files (they are chapters from a book).

Comment: Write a *function* that handles a single file in the way that you want it handled, and then use that to handle all the files.

Answer (score 0):

On the example of one file, if there are more files, before you can say smt like

for file in dir: with open(file) ...., remember that you would also have to change the target file

```
with open('source.txt') as source:
     with open('target.txt','w') as target:
          for line in source.readlines():
              l = line.strip('\n')
              # identify if the 1st char is '-'
              if l[0] == '-':
                 # do somethin e.g. add 'dialog' at the beginning...
                 
                 # skip empty line
              if len(l) == 0:
                 continue
              #Rewrite to target file
              target.write(l + '\n')
     target.close()


source.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your source files in the `source_dir` and you want to output the target files in the `target_dir`, you can do it like that:

```
import os
import path

source_dir = "source_dir"
target_dir = "target_dir"

# on linux or mac, you can get filenames in the specific dir. 
# not sure what will happen on Windows
filenames = os.listdir(source_dir)

for filename in filenames:
    # get full path of source and target file
    filepath_source = path.join(source_dir, filename)
    filepath_target = path.join(target_dir, filename)

    # open source file and target file
    with open(filepath_source) as f_source, open(filepath_target, 'w') as f_target:
        for line in f_source:
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                continue
            if line[0] == '-':
                # do something
            f_target.write(line)
```